# How to copy all text from website + pop up windows?

Tags: html, copy, copy-paste, inspect-element

There's a web page with loads of contact info that I would like to copy to my clipboard and paste into an excel doc. The problem is that in order to display the info (phone, email, title, company, etc...) you have to click on the contact name and then a little blurb comes up (similar to a business card) that shows all info. Thus, I am unable to select all and copy and would have to do this one by one. There are thousands of contacts, so obviously this would be impractical. The hyperlink does not change when I click the blurb.

I'm wondering if there's a workaround to this - is there a program I can use that can extract the info from all of these small blurb-type pop ups that come from one page?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no systematic way to crawl web pages, as it depends on how it was developped.

But you can try this :

1. Click on one such pop-up.
2. With the "dev tools" of your browser, inspect it and find anything you can use to identify this pop-up (for instance it may have a certain class or name).
3. Then, look for this class (or name) in the source code : all the other pop-ups may be there.
4. If so, you can do some text parsing to get the info you want.
5. Finally, you can use something like "search and replace" in a text editor to display the result in an Excel-friendly way.

Comment: Hi Maxime, thanks for the reply. I've tried searching the source code for the information I'm looking for but nothing shows. It seems that the data I want is only available if I click on a single name (even in source and inspect element)